# No Data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, kotlin, request, retrofit

I try to get data from json: https://github.com/rolling-scopes-school/rs.android.task.6/blob/master/data/data.json

Service to prepare retrofit to make the call:

```
object ServiceBuilder {
private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

var gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://github.com/rolling-scopes-school/rs.android.task.6/blob/master/data/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .client(client)
    .build()

fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
    return retrofit.create(service)
  }
 }
```

The Interface:

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/data.json")
fun getItems(): Call <List<Item>>
}
```

MainActivity code:

```
val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call = request.getItems()
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Item>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Item>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Item>>, response: Response<List<Item>>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                recyclerview.apply {
                    progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                    setHasFixedSize(true)
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    adapter = MyAdapter(response.body()!!)
                }
            }
        }

    })
 }
```

MyAdapter:

class MyAdapter(val items: List): RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemsViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, parent, false)
    return ItemsViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
    System.out.println("items.size - " + items.size)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val title = items[position].title ?: ""
    val description = items[position].description ?: ""
    val imageurl = items[position].image.url ?: ""
    holder.bind(title, description, imageurl)
  }
}


class ItemsViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
private val photo: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_photo)
private val title_text: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_)
private val description_text:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)


fun bind(title: String,description:String,imageurl:String) {
    Glide.with(itemView.context).load(imageurl).into(photo)
    title_text.text = title
    description_text.text = description
}
```

Dataclass Item:

```
data class Item(
 val description: String,
 val duration: Duration,
 val enclosure: Enclosure,
 val group: Group,
 val guid: Guid,
 val image: ImageX,
 val link: String,
 val pubDate: String,
 val title: String
)
```

I run app and no such data in screen :-). What's wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be lying here. you are getting the response and you are creating a new adapter each time, but not assigning the new adapter to the recyclerview i guess.

```
 override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Item>>, response: Response<List<Item>>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            recyclerview.apply {
                progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                adapter = MyAdapter(response.body()!!)
                //add this code to assign the adapter and notify the adapter
                recyclerview.adapter = adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

**note**: it would be better if you create your adapter in **onCreate**() and assign the adapter to RecyclerView there only, and now when you call the github api to get the details just update the data in the adapter and call **notifyDataSetChanged** on adapter to notify about the new data changed.

**Edit**: It seems there is issue with the api endpoint also you won't get the json data by hitting that url directly. you need to convert this to raw. something like this.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/rs.android.task.6/master/data/data.json
```

Also the model which you have mentioned won't be mapped by json adapter because the response is in a different format so here change the model to something like below

```
data class GitResponse(val channel: Channel)

data class Channel(val item: List<Item>)
```

so change the retrofit with the following url param.

```
interface ApiInterface {
  @GET
  fun getItems(@Url url: String): Call<GitResponse>
}
```

//and where ever you are call this now pass the full url which is different from the one you have.

```
val url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/rs.android.task.6/master/data/data.json"
val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
val call = request.getItems(url)
call.enqueue(object : Callback<GitResponse> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<GitResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<GitResponse>, response: Response<GitResponse>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            recyclerview.apply {
                progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                adapter = MyAdapter(response.body()?.channel?.item ?: listOf())
                //add this code to assign the adapter and notify 
                recyclerview.adapter = adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

})
```

now you will get the api response, check by applying debug point.

Comment: thanks, but it's not working. I can't get data. still, nothing happens

Comment: can you confirm if the data is coming from api place a debug point there in the onResponse and check

Comment: i try to check.

Comment: I make the control point in code: if (response.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "It's OK!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    System.out.println("Response - "+response).... I do not receive a message

Comment: YES! It's great! working! I get first record from my json. Now I try make good UI :-). Thanks!

Comment: cool, make sure to upvote and accept it has answer so that it helps others also. thanks